# WHERE CLAUSE WITH MULTIPLE CONDITIONS NOT WORKING

Tags: android, database, sqlite

On trying the following code i get the error:

```
Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TRAVEL +
                " WHERE " + KEY_CITY + " = ? AND  " + KEY_STATE + " = ?",null);
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.anvipuri.databaseplaces, PID: 11773
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.anvipuri.databaseplaces/com.anvipuri.databaseplaces.MainActivity}:
>   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested,
>   with a size of 6
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1
>   requested, with a size of 6
>                                                                                    at
>   android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.anvipuri.databaseplaces.DatabaseHelper.findOnep(DatabaseHelper.java:132)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.anvipuri.databaseplaces.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:119)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Obj obj = createObjectFromCursor(cursor);
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Or at least you shouldn't forget to call `moveToPosition()` or `moveToFirst()` so that you initialize the cursor's index from the default `-1`.